# LInkedIn Integration in C#

Tags: asp.net

I haev gone through many articles, but somehow was not able to crack this issue. The linked-in profile of the user will be displayed in my site(Asp.net , C#). When he clicks it , the user needs to be redireceted to the linked-in log in page. once the user logs in , the linked profile will appear.

Is it possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's quite simple out of the box. You have to install the  **Owin.Security.Providers** nuget package.

Then in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
using Owin.Security.Providers.LinkedIn;
```

and then enable the LinkedIn provider in ConfigureAuth:

```
app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(clientId: "...",    clientSecret: "...");
```

Then on the **login** page the link to LinkedIn will appear and your users can use it to login to your website.

Here is a complete walkthrough:

http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/linkedin/guides/aspnet-mvc5/